# SED or AWK to make url querystring readable

Tags: sed, awk, tshark

I need to split a querystring to several unbounded amount of variables for debugging purposes:

The output comes from tshark and the purpose is to live debug google analytics events. The output from tshark looks like this:

```
82.387501       hampus -> domain.net 1261 GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=5.3.7&utms=22&utmn=1234&utmhn=domain.com&utmt=event&utme=5(x*y*z%2Fstart%2Fklipp%2F166_SS%20example)(10)&utmcs=UTF-8~ HTTP/1.1
```

What i want is a more human readable version:

```
utmhn:  domain.com
utmt:   event
utme:   5(x*y*z/start/klipp/166_SS/example)(10)
utmcs:  UTF-8
```

or even better:

```
utmhn:  domain.com
utmt:   event
utme:   5(
          x
          y
          z/start/klipp/166_SS/example
         )(10)
utmcs:  UTF-8
```

But can't get my head around sed (or awk) for this purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using Perl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use strict; use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my @arr;
    my ($qs) = m/.*?GET.*?\?(\S+)\s/;
    my @pairs = split(/[&~]/, $qs);
    foreach my $pair (@pairs){
         my ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
         if ($name eq 'utme') {
            $value =~ s!(%2F|%20)!/!g;
            $value =~ s!\*!\n\t\t!g;
            $value =~ s!\(!(\n\t\t!;
            $value =~ s/\)\(/\n\t)(/;
         }
         # let's URI unescape stuff
         $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
         if ($name eq 'utmhn') {
            print "$name: $value";
        }
        else {
            push @arr, "$name: $value";
        }
    }

    print join "\n", @arr;
    print "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
utmhn: domain.com
utmwv: 5.3.7
utms: 22
utmn: 1234
utmt: event
utme: 5(
                x
                y
                z/start/klipp/166_SS/example
        )(10)
utmcs: UTF-8
```

**USAGE**

```
tshark ... | ./script.pl
```

**ADVANTAGES**

- I take care to display `utmhn:  domain.com` at the first line
- I run an URI unescape on values
- It's not limited to 
  "utmhn",
  "utmt",
  "utme",
  "utmcs" only

Comment: you have a trailing "~" at the end of the last line of output.

Answer (score 3):

**file**

```
82.387501       hampus -> domain.net 1261 GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=5.3.7&utms=22&utmn=1234&utmhn=domain.com&utmt=event&utme=5(x*y*z%2Fstart%2Fklipp%2F166_SS%20example)(10)&utmcs=UTF-8~ HTTP/1.1
```

**command**

```
 sed 's/.*utmhn=/uthmhn:   /
     s/&utmt=/\nutmt:     /
     s/&utme=/\nutme:     /
     s/utmcs=/\nutmcs:    /
     s:[%]2F:/:g
     s:[%]20: :g
     s:[\(]:(\n\t    :
     s:\*:\n\t    :g
     s:[\)]:\n\t  ):
     s/[~].*$//' samp1.txt
```

**output**

```
uthmhn:   domain.com
utmt:     event
utme:     5(
            x
            y
            z/start/klipp/166_SS example
          )(10)&
utmcs:    UTF-8
```

I'm not sure what to say about your %20 VS the expected result of '/' char in your sample data. Did you manually type some of this in?

Comment: **+1** I like this `sed` solution a lot.

Comment: you have a trailing & at the end of the second last line of output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[ \t=&~]+"
    OFS="\t"
}

{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^utmhn$|^utmt$|^utme$|^utmcs$/) {

             if ($i == "utme") {
                 sub(/\(/,"(\n\t  ", $(i+1))
                 gsub(/*/,"\n\t  ", $(i+1))
                 sub(/\)/,"\n\t )", $(i+1))
             }

             print $i":", $(i+1)
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
utmhn:  domain.net
utmt:   event
utme:   5(
          x
          y
          z%2Fstart%2Fklipp%2F166_SS%20example
         )(10)
utmcs:  UTF-8
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[ \t=&~]+"; OFS="\t" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i ~ /^utmhn$|^utmt$|^utme$|^utmcs$/) { if ($i == "utme") { sub(/\(/,"(\n\t  ", $(i+1)); gsub(/*/,"\n\t  ", $(i+1)); sub(/\)/,"\n\t )", $(i+1)) } print $i":", $(i+1) } } }' file.txt
```

Comment: `/^utmhn$|^utmt$|^utme$|^utmcs$/` could be reduced if you like to `/^utm(hn|t|e|cs)$/` or `/^utm(hn|cs|[te])$/`. Changes are all that's really needed is `/^utm..?$/` I suppose.

Comment: intuitive. I don't think the space in `FS` is needed. And I would use `for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2)` assuming that the characters used for FS don't appear somewhere in `key=value` (less robust but less iterations)

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data is in a file called "file":

```
awk -F "&" '{ for ( i=2;i<=NF;i++ ){sub(/=/,":\t",$i);sub(/[~].*$/,"",$i);gsub(/\%2F/,"/",$i);gsub(/\%20/," ",$i);print $i} }' tst
```

produces output:

```
utms:   22
utmn:   1234
utmhn:  domain.com
utmt:   event
utme:   5(x*y*z/start/klipp/166_SS example)(10)
utmcs:  UTF-8
```

it's a bit dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[&=~]"; OFS=":\t" }
{
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      map[$i]=$(i+1)
   }

   sub(/\(/,"&\n\t  ", map["utme"])
   gsub(/\*/,"\n\t  ", map["utme"])
   gsub(/%2./,"/",     map["utme"])
   sub(/\)/,"\n\t&",   map["utme"])

   print "utmhn", map["utmhn"]
   print "utmt",  map["utmt"]
   print "utme",  map["utme"]
   print "utmcs", map["utmcs"]
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
utmhn:  domain.com
utmt:   event
utme:   5(
          x
          y
          z/start/klipp/166_SS/example
        )(10)
utmcs:  UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*\(utmhn.*=\S*\).*/\1/;s/&/\n/g;s/=/:\t/g;s/(/&\n\t/;s/*/\n\t/g;s/%2F/\//g;s/%20/ /g;s/)/\n\t&/' file
```